# Quantile crossing with Quantile Regression Forests

Tags: random-forest, quantiles, quantile-regression

I'm looking for a way to perform multiple simultaneous quantile regression.

I read that the quantile crossing phenomenon is a common issue for that type of tasks, and I must avoid it.

So my question is : does Quantile Forest Regression prevent quantile crossing, or not? If not, could you a better suited method?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, quantiles of QFR **never cross**.

Accordingly to [the paper of Meinshausen](http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume7/meinshausen06a/meinshausen06a.pdf), quantile regresion forest works as follows:

**fit**: just fit an ordinary ransom forest

**predict**: for an observation $x$, take all the trainging samples that shared leaves with $x$, and return their quantiles.

Because the algoritm always returns "real" quantiles (although maybe of somehow "imaginary" distribution), they are ordered properly for each possible test sample.